# textarea scrollbars overflow and hide div border

Tags: html, textarea, overflow, border, scrollbars

I've tried this on many browsers ( via browsershots ) and universally the scrollbars overflow and hide the green border.

I don't want `overflow: hidden` because that clips the scrollbars.

How do I get the scrollbars inside the border, instead of obscuring the border?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid green; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100px;">
    <div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; position: relative; float: left; width: 20%; height: 100%;">
        <select style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple >
        <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; float: left; width: 80%; height: 100%;">
        <form style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline; position: relative;">
            <textarea readonly="readonly" style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:scroll;" wrap="off" >
            </textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text area must have rows attribute.
Rows assume font size.
Font size and rows will overflow the container.